Maximizing LoRa range on Seeed Studio's WiO E5 mini
Some collaborators and I are working on a sensor device. We plan on using Seeed studio's Wio E5 mini, but we are struggling a bit with getting a good range on our communication. We are utilising Jan Gromeš' RadioLib library, and after a parameter test we ended up on using the following parameters:
static const float LoRa_bw                      = 125.0;
static const int LoRa_sf                        = 8;
static const int LoRa_cr                        = 6;
static const int LoRa_power                     = 15;

where sf is the spreading factor, cr is the coding rate, bw the bandwith, and power the output power in dBM. We are broadcasting on the EU 868 MHz band. However, with these settings, we still experience quite low RSSI ( typically -100 dBm at ~100 m) , which is far from ideal. So I was wondering if you have any tips, tricks or ideas on how to proceed if we want to improve the radio range. A code example is given below:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <RadioLib.h>

// no need to configure pins, signals are routed to the radio internally
STM32WLx radio = new STM32WLx_Module();

// set RF switch configuration for Nucleo WL55JC1

static const uint32_t rfswitch_pins[] = {PA4,  PA5, RADIOLIB_NC, RADIOLIB_NC, RADIOLIB_NC};
static const Module::RfSwitchMode_t rfswitch_table[] = {
  {STM32WLx::MODE_IDLE,  {LOW,  LOW}},
  {STM32WLx::MODE_RX,    {LOW, HIGH}},
  {STM32WLx::MODE_TX_HP, {HIGH, LOW}},
  END_OF_MODE_TABLE,
};

// save transmission state between loops
int transmissionState = RADIOLIB_ERR_NONE;
uint8_t sf = 8;
double freq = 868.2;
double bw = 125;
uint8_t cr = 6;
uint8_t power = 15;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // set RF switch control configuration
  // this has to be done prior to calling begin()
  radio.setRfSwitchTable(rfswitch_pins, rfswitch_table);

  Serial.print(F("[STM32WL] Initializing ... "));
  int state = radio.begin(freq, bw, sf, cr, (0x12), power,8, 1.7, false);

  if (state == RADIOLIB_ERR_NONE) {
    Serial.println(F("success!"));
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("failed, code "));
    Serial.println(state);
    while (true) { delay(10); }
  }

  // set appropriate TCXO voltage for Nucleo WL55JC1
  state = radio.setTCXO(1.7);

  if (state == RADIOLIB_ERR_NONE) {
    Serial.println(F("success!"));
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("failed, code "));
    Serial.println(state);
    while (true) { delay(10); }
  }

  // set the function that will be called
  // when packet transmission is finished
  radio.setDio1Action(setFlag);


}

// flag to indicate that a packet was sent
volatile bool transmittedFlag = false;

// this function is called when a complete packet
// is transmitted by the module
void setFlag(void) {
  // we sent a packet, set the flag
  transmittedFlag = true;
}

// counter to keep track of transmitted packets
int count = 0;

void loop() {
  // check if the previous transmission finished
  if(transmittedFlag) {
    // reset flag
    transmittedFlag = false;

    if (transmissionState == RADIOLIB_ERR_NONE) {
      // packet was successfully sent
      Serial.println(F("transmission finished!"));
    } else {
      Serial.print(F("failed, code "));
      Serial.println(transmissionState);

    }

    // clean up after transmission is finished
    // this will ensure transmitter is disabled,
    // RF switch is powered down etc.
    radio.finishTransmit();

    // wait a second before transmitting again
    delay(1000);

    String str = "Hello World! I am sending yet another package with ID #" + String(count++);
    transmissionState = radio.startTransmit(str);
  }
  delay(400);
}


What kind of antenna are you using? What dBm should be expected from the datasheet?

The critical thing for radio is the antennas. Don’t expect to get great range with little stick antennas.

and can you link to the datasheet of the exact chip used on the board? this should be some for of stm32wl I think? :)

Thanks for the quick replies. The Wio E5 comes with one of these 2.6 dBm antennas:
https://www.seeedstudio.com/External-Antenna-915MHZ-2-6dBi-SMA-L195mm-p-5047.html
Which we are using for the trasnmitter (it needs to be small and installed on a floating buoy.) For the base station, we have tried with both a similar antenna and one of these 8 dBm high gain antennas:
https://www.seeedstudio.com/RF-Explorer-LoRa-Fiberglass-Antenna-Kit-863-870MHz-8dBi-1300mm-p-5277.html
What is strange is that the small 2.6 dB antennas perform better than the high gain ones.

And the datasheet can be found here:
https://files.seeedstudio.com/products/317990687/res/LoRa-E5%20module%20datasheet_V1.1.pdf
This is a slightly modified STM32WL55JC

8dbi is a pretty low gain antenna for long range communications. If you know which direction the buoy is relative to the base station get a high gain antenna and point it at the buoy.

@user1850479  For LORA those antenna gains are very adequate if other factors are OK.

@LarsWillasDreyer   You may wish to "deaccept" my answer for now. That tends to encourage others to answer and someone else may have some good things to say. You can reaccept after a week or two if nobody else answers, if you wish. (The rep is always nice to have but I don't need it :-) and some others want it. I'd be interested in knowing more about your project - is it mentioned online elsewhere? How big are the bouys and can you get the aerial higher off the water. Fresnel zones MAY be less important on a smooth uncluttered surface as they are about multipath reflections back to the RX.

@Russel McMahon. Thanks for your suggestion and sorry for the late reply, it is a great tip. We will try some tests tomorrow to see if we get better results when transmitting across a lake outside of the city. (And I wrote this little post about the project if you are still interested in reading more about it. , which I hope is a good read)

If you can get the aerial higher it should help.
If you have not met them web-search Fresnel zones.
For an antenna at surtface level this can be a  major factor.
The aerials you mention should give good range with LORA if you can get them up off the surface. If not the buoy end then raising just the other may help.
You MAY be able to add a "mast" to the buoy to improve Fresnel zone effects.
A 1/4 wave at 860 MHz is ~= 86 mm so a quite thin light mast could add substantial height.  A 5/8 wavelength is ~= 220 mm and gives useful gain over a 1/4 wave and is cheap, simple and compact.
You want to start by setting all LORA parameters as conservatively as possible (you may have done so.) Lowest air data rate, max TX power, broadest spreading factor, ... . Also look at shifting frequency in case there is something on the standard one.
2.4 GHz LORA is available but probably mot as an STM module.
You get more path loss BUT better Fresnel zone clearances for a given height.
Antennas are about 3 x shorter for same gain so more gain possible for given size. Look at a 5/8 wavelength J pole or similar.
I'm about to try 2.4 GHZ LORA in place of 46x MHz I've been using.
My aerial heights are also constrained but not as badly as yours.
